# Get leaf node rows only in parent child tree structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, treeview, recursive-query

Using SQL, How can I get just the leaf nodes of a tree structure.  In my example I have the data as shown but I just want to return those rows with an 'x' next to them.  I need a generic piece of SQL that can handle multiple depths.

[image: Example]

Comment: `WHERE Level = 4 or (ParentLineID IS NULL and LineID <> 3255)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find items with no children:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM table_name T2
            WHERE T1.LineId=T2.ParentLineId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Select * 
 From  YourTable 
 Where LineID not in (Select Distinct ParentLineID From YourTable)
```